# Rails 4 - Order of has_many, through nested attributes in form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

**tl,dr**: How can I ensure that the order of my has_many, through nested attributes, with an attribute value set in the build, are always assigned the same nested parameters hash key number (0, 1, etc.) and always appear in the form in the same order?

Hopefully I can describe this so it makes sense.  I have a small prototype app that simulates a simple bank transfer between two accounts, a source account and a destination account. I have a `Transfer` class, an `Account` class and a `TransferAccounts` class that is the through join for the many_to_many association between `Transfer` and `Account`.

Here is the `new` action in the `TransfersController`:

```
def new
  @transfer = Transfer.new
  @transfer.transfer_accounts.build(account_transfer_role: 'source').build_account
  @transfer.transfer_accounts.build(account_transfer_role: 'destination').build_account
  bank_selections
  account_selections
end
```

And the strong parameters:

```
def transfer_params
  params.require(:transfer).
    permit(:name, :description,
           transfer_accounts_attributes:
             [:id, :account_id, :account_transfer_role,
              account_attributes:
                [:id, :bank_id, :name, :description, :user_name,
                 :password, :routing_number, :account_number
                ]
             ])
end
```

So, the two `transfer_accounts` associated with a `transfer` each have an `account_transfer_role` attribute, with one of them set to *source* and the other set to *destination*.

Now, when filling in the form and submitting, the parameters look like the following in console:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
"transfer"=>{"name"=>"Test Transfer 2", "description"=>"Second test transfer",
"transfer_accounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"account_transfer_role"=>"source", "account_id"=>"1",
"account_attributes"=>{"bank_id"=>"1", "name"=>"George's Checking",
"description"=>"George's personal checking account", "user_name"=>"georgeckg",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "account_number"=>"111111111", "routing_number"=>"101010101",
"id"=>"3"}, "id"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"account_transfer_role"=>"destination", "account_id"=>"2",
"account_attributes"=>{"bank_id"=>"2", "name"=>"George's Savings",
"description"=>"George's personal savings account", "user_name"=>"georgesav",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "account_number"=>"111101111", "routing_number"=>"100100100",
"id"=>"4"}, "id"=>"4"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Transfer", "id"=>"2"}
```

As you can see, each `transfer_account` in the the `transfer_account_attributes` hash has an id key, either a **0** or a **1** (e.g. `..."0"=>{"account_transfer_role"=>"source"...`). Now, I have been working under the assumption (which I thought might come back to bite me, and it has) that because of the order they are built in the `new` action, that the *source* `transfer_account` would always have an id key of *0* and the *destination* `transfer_account` would always have an id key of *1*, which led me to use these id keys elsewhere in the controller as though *0* represented *source* and *1* represented *destination*.

And all seemed to be working fine until I was trying different permutations of creating new or using existing accounts, creating new or editing existing transfers when suddenly the form appears with *destination* listed **first** and *source* **second**, which hadn't occurred before, causing the entries to now have *destination* associated with *0* and *source* associated with *1*, breaking the code in the controller referred to above.

To make it clearer, here is the form:

```
#transfer_form
  = simple_form_for @transfer do |t|
    .form-inputs

      = t.input :name, label: 'Transfer Name'
      = t.input :description, required: false, label: 'Transfer Description'

      = t.simple_fields_for :transfer_accounts do |ta|

        - role = ta.object.account_transfer_role.titleize
        = ta.input :account_transfer_role, as: :hidden

        = ta.input :account_id, collection:    @valid_accounts,
                                include_blank: 'Select account...',
                                label:         "#{ role } Account",
                                error:         'Account selection is required.'

        .account_fields{id: "#{ role.downcase }_account_fields"}

          = ta.simple_fields_for :account do |a|

            = a.input :bank_id,        collection:    @valid_banks,
                                       include_blank: 'Select bank...',
                                       label:         "#{ role } Bank",
                                       error:         'Bank selection is required.',
                                       class:         "#{ role.downcase }_account_input_field"

            = a.input :name,           label:    "#{ role } Account Name",
                                       class:    "#{ role.downcase }_account_input_field"

            = a.input :description,    required: false,
                                       label:    "#{ role } Account Description",
                                       class:    "#{ role.downcase }_account_input_field"

            = a.input :user_name,      label:    "#{ role } Account User Name",
                                       class:    "#{ role.downcase }_account_input_field"

            = a.input :password,       label:    "#{ role } Account Password",
                                       class:    "#{ role.downcase }_account_input_field"

            = a.input :account_number, label:    "#{ role } Account Number",
                                       class:    "#{ role.downcase }_account_input_field"

            = a.input :routing_number, label:    "#{ role } Account Routing Number",
                                       class:    "#{ role.downcase }_account_input_field"

    = t.submit
```

How do I ensure that ***source is always first*** and, thus, always associated with the id key ***0*** and ***destination is always second***, always associated with the id key ***1***?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be as simple as changing the `:transfer_accounts` association line in my `Transfer` model from this:

```
has_many  :transfer_accounts, inverse_of: :transfer
```

to this:

```
has_many  :transfer_accounts, -> { order('account_transfer_role DESC') }, inverse_of: :transfer
```

If anyone believes it is not doing what I think it is doing, please let me know, because, at the moment it appears to be resolving my issue.

Comment: What you do here is simply asking the database to give you back the `transfer_accounts` by alphabetical order of the `account_transfer_role`. This feels bad because this impacts all your queries to `transfer_accounts`while you only need to *display* them in that order.